# Работа со строками и файлами на с++

Tags: c++, строки, файлы, случайные-числа

Нужно написать программу,которая из одного файла случайным образом выбирает 3 пункта списка и записывает в другой. Написала небольшой код, но не получается сделать так,чтобы числа были разными :(

```
include <iostream>
include <fstream>
include <string>
include <windows.h>
include <ctime>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "Russian");

    int a, r1, r2, r3;

    ifstream fin("ekz.txt");
    ofstream fout("voprosi.txt");

    string line;

    cin >> a;  // ввод количества строк в файле "ekz.txt"

    srand(time(0));

    r1 = 1 + rand() % a;
    r2 = 1 + rand() % a;
    r3 = 1 + rand() % a;


    for (size_t line_no = r1; line_no && getline(fin, line);--line_no);  //выводит строку под номером,заданным r1
    fout << line << endl;

    for (size_t line_no = r2; line_no && getline(fin, line);--line_no);  //выводит строку под номером,заданным r2
    fout << line << endl;

    for (size_t line_no = r3; line_no && getline(fin, line);--line_no);  //выводит строку под номером,заданным r3
    fout << line << endl;

    fout.close();
    fin.close();

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: А еще у вас `fin` надо сбрасывать после каждого цикла в начало файла, иначе при 1,2,3 вы прочтете первую, третью и шестую строки... Если они, конечно, есть в файле :)

Answer (score 1):

Не совсем понял,что вам именно нужно,но если нужно сгенерировать случайным образом числа из определенного отрезка ,например [2,5],то вот решение.

rand()%(разница между границами+1)+левая граница

```
// если а-левая граница, b-правая, то:
    rand()%(b-a+1) + a;
```